# SQL updating with string concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, string-concatenation

I am attempting to update a one-to-many row but the end result is a one-to-one update.  Basically, I have a string column that I want to concatenate all of the results returned from the join (the order of the update does not matter).

```
-- destination table
CREATE TABLE #TmpRes (SiteID bigint,ResString nvarchar(28) );
insert into #TmpRes (SiteID,ResString) values (1,'..'), (2,'..'), (3,'..');

-- join table (I only want to update SiteID #2)
CREATE TABLE #TmpData (DataNum bigint,DataStr nvarchar(28) );
insert into #TmpData (DataNum,DataStr) values (2,'CC'), (2,'BB'), (2,'AA');

-- this shows that the join is correct
select 'TJoin' TableName, *
FROM #TmpRes tr 
    join #TmpData td ON (tr.SiteID=td.DataNum) -- [1]

-- This update is only updating 1 row when it should be 3 rows
update #TmpRes 
    set ResString=tr.ResString + td.DataStr + tr.ResString
FROM #TmpRes tr 
    join #TmpData td ON (tr.SiteID=td.DataNum)

select '#TmpData' TableName, * from #TmpData --[2]

-- **expecting to see record 2 ResString to look like**
-- **..CC....BB....AA..**
select '#TmpRes' TableName, * from #TmpRes --[3]
```

Result of the above `SELECT`s:

1:

```
TJoin,2,..,2,CC

TJoin,2,..,2,BB

TJoin,2,..,2,AA
```

2:

```
TmpData,2,CC

TmpData,2,BB

TmpData,2,AA
```

3:

```
TmpRes,1,..

TmpRes,2,..CC..

TmpRes,3,..
```

---

I am using SQLServer 2014 but I am sure the result will be the same for any SQL Server.

Comment: How can the join update three rows? You're matching on siteid = datanum, and one table only has datanum of 2. What exactly do you expect siteid 1 / 3 to look like after the update?

Comment: What are you seeing as a result of the last select?   Please edit your question with the desired result and the current actual results in tabular format.

Comment: I'd recommend that you do ***not*** do this.  It is non-relational, and there is no good reason apparent here why you would need this.  The data is already correctly structured as one-to-many across two tables, just use that.  If you really need to format many values into one column for some client application, then only do it when you return the data to that client.  Do not compound this massive mistake by propagating into your database schema.

Comment: The result of the select is

Comment: This all started about a month ago and I saw the problem then and tried to find an alternate solution but I have not found one.  The end result is for a SSRS report and so far this has been the best possible solution.

Comment: the output is not formatting wll

Comment: Please edit the question.   It is too hard to post query results in a readable format in a comment.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4666 - of course it would be easier to just do this in a query at runtime than to use all these #temp tables and update those. For example, this query doesn't require any updates (and may enable you to ultimately drop the expensive #temp tables, too): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4667

Comment: give your desired result of update too, to give you the solution

Comment: Aaron,  I am only expecting SiteID 2 to be updated.  I am not expecting SiteID 1 or 3 to be updated and they are just there to show data (I should have eliminated them for this posting).

Comment: someone, please explain how I received a -1 for a question.  I thought that it was complete question with results (not the results I wanted).  and the first answer below is using SUFF which does not solve my question at all.  farheg solution answers my question completely but I do not have a high enough rating to bump up his score.

Answer (score 0):

> -- expecting to see record 2 ResString to look like:
>
> -- ..CC....BB....AA..

I think you want to update the table on base of concatenating the specific values of rows of other table, you can use do it by using `FOR XML PATH` within a `subquery`:

```
update tmr 
    set tmr.ResString=(
                select tr.ResString + td.DataStr
                FROM #TmpRes tr 
                join #TmpData td ON (tr.SiteID=td.DataNum)
                where tr.SiteID=tmr.SiteID
                For XML PATH ('')
                )
FROM #TmpRes tmr 
    join #TmpData td ON (tmr.SiteID=td.DataNum)
```

Checking the result:

```
select '#TmpRes' TableName, * from #TmpRes

TableName   SiteID  ResString
#TmpRes       1     ..
#TmpRes       2     ..CC..BB..AA
#TmpRes       3     ..
```

Comment: Thank you Farheg.  I have not used 'For XML Path' and not exactly sure how it works but it is something for me to research to understand.

Comment: You are welcome, well, try it, it's very useful for concatenating rows